# Bindings to periodically updated property do not update automatically

Tags: java, javafx, properties, binding

When I create a binding to a property using Bindings.createStringBinding the binding does not update when the property value updates.

```java
public class Test extends Application {

    private static Duration timeLeft(LocalDateTime end) {
        return Duration.between(LocalDateTime.now(), end);
    }

    // note: the returned Duration property class is java.time.Duration, not javafx.util.Duration
    private static ObjectProperty<Duration> timeUntil(LocalDateTime end) {
        SimpleObjectProperty<Duration> property = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(timeLeft(end));
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
        KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(javafx.util.Duration.seconds(1), e -> property.set(timeLeft(end)));
        timeline.getKeyFrames().add(keyFrame);
        timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.play();
        return property;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        LocalDateTime end = LocalDateTime.now().plusSeconds(10);
        ObjectProperty<Duration> timeLeft = timeUntil(end);
        Label label = new Label();
        label.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
            if (timeLeft(end).isNegative()) {
                return "Finished.";
            } else {
                return timeLeft(end).toSeconds() + " seconds left";
            }
        }, timeLeft));

        Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane(label), 320, 240);

        stage.setTitle("Test");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Now if inside the binding lambda I use `timeLeft.get()` (meaning that I get the value from the property instead of recalculating it with the timeLeft method) the binding does update. This is however odd behavior and I wonder if I am doing something wrong somewhere else. I am not sure if this is an intended but undocumented behavior of bindings or if it is a bug with JavaFX.

Another workaround I found is, inside the KeyFrame handler calling `property.get()` directly after I have set the value.

Comment: This is expected behavior. Standard JavaFX properties are as lazy as possible. They will not fire invalidation events if they are already invalid. By calling `get()` you are validating the property, meaning the next time it changes it will fire an invalidation event, causing the binding to also become invalid (and fire an invalidation event). Without that call to `get()`, the property never becomes valid and therefore never notifies the binding after the first invalidation.

Comment: Ok I understand. Better leave the question open in case somebody else has the same issue. I actually did not find out that it was due to not calling `get()` inside the binding until I created a test application.